# Entity Framework: Global Navigation Tree

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I would like to expose a navigation pane in my WPF app, which shows all the different objects in my database, each of which will have children. Each child can have additional children, and there can be any number of levels (in practice this will likely be limited to 5 levels).

In order to load these projects and their associated children, I tried this approach:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects {get;set;} //Will implement INotifyPropertyChanged here

    public void LoadAllProjects()
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            context.Projects.Load();
            this.Projects = context.Projects;
        }                
    }
}
```

Each project above will have children (with potentially more children) as described. As you can imagine, the above code doesn't work and gives me the "context has been disposed" exception as soon as I try to expand the NavigationTree in my WPF front-end. How can I expose these properties in the navigation tree so that they are loaded every time the user expands a project (or a project child) in the NavigationTree?

Ideally I'd like this link to be 'live', i.e. so that when changes are made in the database, they are shown in this NavigationTree (the app will support multiple users, who can work on the same project / different project in same database at the same time).

Is this a use case for a singleton Context() instance?

Comment: well, I'm not super familiar with wpf lifecycle, but what I can tell you is that your problem occurs because the `Context` is being disposed at the end of the `using` statement. You could try this: remove the `using` statement, declare your context as a property of `DataModel` and do not call the `Dispose` method. Then, run the app and try to expand the properties in the client. Not sure if it will work, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick solution to this error try to use an ObservableCollection constructor instead of assigning. In constructor it will copy all elements to new collection, so your view model will be independent of DbContext:

```
this.Projects = new ObservableCollection(context.Projects);
```

To decide how to use DbContext in your application look at a very good article: [Managing DbContext the right way with Entity Framework 6: an in-depth guide](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/).

The main idea is to keep DbContext alive inside a business transaction scope. And the author offers special DbContextScope class to define business transaction boundaries in which DbContext's may be used.

Comment: Thanks, I've devided to keep the context open while the user is busy modifying a specific project.